# How to use find with regex to delete files beginning with certain letters

Tags: linux, regex

I have a nested directory structure that looks like this:

```
top_dir
└── nested_1
    └── nested_2
        ├── a_file.txt
        ├── b_file.txt
        ├── directory
        ├── other_directory
        ├── y_file.txt
        └── z_file.txt
```

I want to delete the files inside `nested_2` that don't start with A-M, and leave the directories alone. So I want to delete `y_file.txt` and `z_file.txt`.

I need to run the find + regex command in `top_dir`.

I've tried multiple versions of this:

```
find nested_1/nested_2 -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f -regex "nested_1\/nested_2\/.*^[a-m]" #-delete
```

It doesn't seem to matter what regex I use - the only one that produces any result at all is

```
find nested_1/nested_2 -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f -regex ".*" #-delete
```

which just gives me a list of all the files in the directory with the leading nested directories (as expected).

Testing it out on regexr hasn't helped either.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `^[a-m]` should be `[^a-m]`.
2. After the first letter there may be the rest of the filename, so you need `.*` *after* `[^a-m]`, not before.
3. These backshlashes are not needed (they don't hurt though).

```
find nested_1/nested_2 -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f -regex "nested_1/nested_2/[^a-m].*" #-delete
```

Notes:

- Linux and its filesystems are case sensitive. Things "that don't start with A-M" would be `[^A-M].*`.
- Sometimes `[^a-m]` (or `[^A-M]`) [may not be what you think](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/227070/108618).

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes, the lack of closing quote was a typo. Super frustrating to learn that the caret being inside the bracket was the main problem, but hey... that's programming :)